# System image to be loaded to QEMU

Tags: boot, virtualization, system, qemu, snapshot

Is there any way to take a snapshot of my current system and load it on another computer to QEMU?

Comment: This would require me to make a "clean" install of ubuntu and replace it with my image.  I am seeking for something more automated.

Comment: I don't understand why a "snapshot of my current system" requires you to make a "clean" install. I do not know any automated tools to migrate.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!